# Animating Bindings in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, binding, swiftui

I have the following code which partially shows or hides the `Test` view depending on a `Binding<Bool>`. I can wrap the `testVisible.toggle()` call in a `withAnimation`, however, ideally I would like to ensure that `visible` binding is always animated, even when called without a `withAnimation`. How can I make sure that whenever `visible` binding is changed, the change is animated?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var testVisible: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .onTapGesture {
                    testVisible.toggle()
                }
            
            Test(visible: $testVisible)
        }
            
    }
}

struct Test: View {
    @Binding var visible: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .opacity(visible ? 0.5 : 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `.animation()` modifier to the `Text` view:

```
struct Test: View {
    @Binding var visible: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .opacity(visible ? 0.5 : 0)
            .animation(.linear(duration: 0.5))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The simple `.animation()` modifier is deprecated in iOS 15 and macOS 12. You need to add a value, which the animation is based on:

```
struct Test: View {
    @Binding var visible: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .opacity(visible ? 0.5 : 0)
            .animation(.linear(duration: 0.5), value: visible)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake, in `Test: View` it should be a `let visible`  not a `@Binding var`. `let` is for read access and `@Binding var` is when you need write access which you don't. This version animates in and out correctly:

```
    struct ContentView3: View {
        @State var testVisible: Bool = true
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Color.white
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            testVisible.toggle()
                        }
                        
                    }
                
                Test(visible: testVisible)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    struct Test: View {
        let visible: Bool
        
        var body: some View {
            Text("Test")
                .opacity(visible ? 0.5 : 0)
        }
    }
```